# Android: keep initial size of ImageView (src) into a responsive LinearLayout (without dp)

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview, drawable, responsive

### Context

I'm looking to create a board game (like chess) on Android with a fullscreen responsive board compatible with any screen (landscape), using **`LinearLayout`** including **`match_parent`**, **`wrap_content`** and also a complex mix of **`weightSum`** and **`layout_weight`** for keep the same look regardless of the screen:

- [see the context screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZDiK.png)

---

### Issue

As you can see, it works fine until the last child elements that are **`ImageView`** but the moment I try to put a **`background`** or **`src`**, the size of the **`ImageView`** element changes completely and breaks the appearance of the board; while the **`foreground`** does not pose any problem:

- [(OK) see screenshot with foreground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34olb.png)
- [(KO) see screenshot with background or src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lum1E.png)

---

### Tries

Put the **`foregroundGravity`** on **`fill`** works for the **`foreground`** resource whatever the type of **`drawable`**; whereas any parameter for **`scaleType`** (**`fitCenter`**, **`centerCrop`**, etc.), **`layout_gravity`** (**`fill`**, **`center`**, etc.) or **`adjustViewBounds`** does not seem to give the expected result and changes the size of the box.

You can try yourself with my XML code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/field"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="8800">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1000"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearFieldC"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="745"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:weightSum="15640">

        /* some ImageView */

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearFieldB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="760"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:weightSum="15640">

        /* some ImageView */

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearFieldA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="780"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:weightSum="15640">

        /* some ImageView */

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearField0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="800"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:weightSum="15640">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/goal0F"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="919"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:padding="0dp">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square0E"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="919"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:padding="0dp">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square0D"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="919"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:padding="0dp">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square0C"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="919"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:padding="0dp">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square0B"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="919"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:padding="0dp">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square0A"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="919"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:padding="0dp">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square00"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="919"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:padding="0dp">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="919"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:padding="0dp">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="919"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:padding="0dp">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="919"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:padding="0dp">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="919"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:padding="0dp">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square05"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="919"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:padding="0dp">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/goal06"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="919"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill"
            android:foregroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:padding="0dp">

        </ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearField1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="840"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:weightSum="15640">

        /* some ImageView */

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearField2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="850"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:weightSum="15640">

        /* some ImageView */

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearField3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="855"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:weightSum="15640">

        /* some ImageView */

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearFooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2170"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

### Lead

However, inspired by Android buttons, I made a **`drawable`** that does not change the appearance of the box when it used on **`background`** or **`src`** but it remains limited in terms of visual content; I wonder if there was not a lead to follow to force the behavior of other types of resources (vector, png, etc.)?

For example, this kind of **`drawable`** works when its put on **`background`** or **`src`** without resize **`ImageView`**; using **`padding`** at 0 and a transparency **`stroke`** to simulate a virtual **`padding`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="0dp"
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetRight="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp">
    <ripple android:color="@android:color/black">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#26000000"/>
                <stroke
                    android:color="#00000000"
                    android:width="8dp">
                </stroke>
                <padding
                    android:left="0dp"
                    android:top="0dp"
                    android:right="0dp"
                    android:bottom="0dp">
                </padding>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </ripple>
</inset>
```

---

### Help

Could you help me to put the **`drawable`** in **`src`** of my **`ImageView`** without resizing it? Of course, it would be easier to do it with HTML/CSS/JS, too bad!

Thanks a lot for any idea!

Comment: Warnings appearing on screenshots are not linked to my issue, they just say that nested weights (on LinearLayout) are bad for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How does Android work?

Android seems apply view properties in a specific order in such a way that the **`layout_weight`** of my **`ImageView`**, associated to its parent container, is secondary than its own size parameter.

So if **`ImageView`** **`layout_width`** or **`layout_height`** (depending of your **`LinearLayout`** **`orientation`**) is **`wrap_content`** and this content is bigger than **`ImageView`**, its final size will be as big as its content and surely bigger in my case.

---

### Issue resolved

Knowing this, you can make a smallest **`drawable`** as possible for your content in such a way that it will fill the **`ImageView`** (only with vector files, not advised with bitmap resources).

You can also simply force the **`ImageView`** **`layout_width`** (or **`layout_height`**) at 0dp if you apply a **`layout_weight`**.

---

I thank Quentin and Peter for their advice and hope this resolved issue will help you!